# Difference between sentences using 'was' and 'being'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, participles, present-participles

What is the meaning of below sentences using was and being?

> He committed suicide after he *was* severely beaten up by four teachers. 
> He committed suicide after *being* severely beaten up by four teachers.

Comment: another possibility -*after having beaten....!*

Comment: @MaulikV - not unless it was _after having been beaten_, or your version would change the meaning!

Answer (score 3):

There is no practical difference in meaning. In other words the two sentences mean the same thing. They both mean that first, he was beaten up, and after that, he committed suicide.

This also makes logical sense since the term *to beat up* is usually applied to living people, not to dead ones, or corpses. In other words you can beat up someone before they commit suicide, but not afterwards. Not really. You could beat up the corpse, but most people would consider a living being different from a corpse.

The first sentence uses two finite clauses, each having a finite verb (*committed*, *was beaten up*); and the second uses a finite verb (*committed*) in the independent clause, and a participial (*being beaten up*) in a dependent clause.

There is no difference in meaning, just two ways of building sentences.

Here's [a website](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/verbs/finite.htm) with a simple explanation about the difference between a finite verb and a nonfinite verb.